# How to find a specific word within a phrase?

Tags: sql, oracle

I wish to know how to find a specific word within a phrase. I am trying to find the word "Pizza" within a set of keywords, however there is no keyword that only has "Pizza". There are keywords such as "Pizza Delivery" and "Pizza Delivery Boy", however they won't show up! How can I do this?

Desired output:

```
MOVIE                               KEYWORD                         
----------------------------------- ----------------------------------
Drive Angry                         Waitress                                                                                            
Taken                               France                                                                                              
Saving Private Ryan                 France
30 Minutes or Less                  Pizza Delivery
30 Minutes or Less                  Pizza Delivery Boy
```

My script:

```
SELECT MovieTitle AS "MOVIE", KEYWORDDESC AS "KEYWORD"
FROM TBLMOVIE
JOIN TBLKEYWORDDETAIL ON TBLMOVIE.MOVIEID = TBLKEYWORDDETAIL.MOVIEID
JOIN TBLKEYWORD ON TBLKEYWORDDETAIL.KEYWORDID = TBLKEYWORD.KEYWORDID
WHERE TBLKEYWORD.KEYWORDDESC IN ('France', 'Waitress', 'Pizza');
```

My output:

```
MOVIE                               KEYWORD                         
----------------------------------- ----------------------------------
Drive Angry                         Waitress                                                                                            
Taken                               France                                                                                              
Saving Private Ryan                 France
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `LIKE`:

```
WHERE TBLKEYWORD.KEYWORDDESC LIKE '%France%' OR
      TBLKEYWORD.KEYWORDDESC LIKE '%Waitress%' OR
      TBLKEYWORD.KEYWORDDESC LIKE '%Pizza%'
```

Another method uses `REGEXP_LIKE()`:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(TBLKEYWORD.KEYWORDDESC, 'France|Waitress|Pizza')
```

If you use `REGEXP_LIKE()` you should spend a little bit of time learning about regular expressions and how to use them.